# Genymotion emulator error trying to load javacv / opencv libs with static initialization

Tags: android, opencv, genymotion, javacv, eclipse-adt

Getting this error, no matter which genymotion virtual device I choose:

`dlopen("/data/app-lib/com.brainlogin.facedetectlib-1/libjniavutil.so") failed: dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/libhoudini.so" not found`

I'm initiating javacv statically (I have all the .so files in my lib folder). 
My code to load the libraries
System.loadLibrary("detection_based_tracker");

I've also tried manually trigger loading libopencv_java based on other posts:

System.loadLibrary("libopencv_java");
System.loadLibrary("detection_based_tracker");

Note that the same app runs fine on Eclipse's ADT emulators and on physical devices.
Also note that my other apps not having javacv run fine on the Genymotion virtual devices.

Here is the full logcat:

```
02-21 11:33:49.177: D/AndroidRuntime(1673): CheckJNI is OFF
02-21 11:33:49.185: D/dalvikvm(1673): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
02-21 11:33:49.185: D/dalvikvm(1673): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
02-21 11:33:49.189: D/dalvikvm(1673): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
02-21 11:33:49.189: D/dalvikvm(1673): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
02-21 11:33:49.189: D/dalvikvm(1673): No JNI_OnLoad found in libnativehelper.so 0x0, skipping init
02-21 11:33:49.201: D/dalvikvm(1673): Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 179 unimplemented (abstract) methods
02-21 11:33:49.241: E/memtrack(1673): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
02-21 11:33:49.241: E/android.os.Debug(1673): failed to load memtrack module: -2
02-21 11:33:49.265: D/AndroidRuntime(1673): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
02-21 11:33:49.273: I/ActivityManager(540): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.brainlogin.facedetectlib/.FaceDetect} from pid 1673
02-21 11:33:49.281: D/(540): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8ba2cf8, tid 552
02-21 11:33:49.509: D/dalvikvm(540): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 340K, 51% free 6547K/13196K, paused 7ms, total 7ms
02-21 11:33:49.509: I/dalvikvm-heap(540): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.285MB for 856092-byte allocation
02-21 11:33:49.521: D/dalvikvm(540): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 48% free 7380K/14036K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
02-21 11:33:49.529: D/dalvikvm(540): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 48% free 7384K/14036K, paused 7ms, total 7ms
02-21 11:33:49.533: I/dalvikvm-heap(540): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.103MB for 856092-byte allocation
02-21 11:33:49.541: D/dalvikvm(540): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 45% free 8220K/14876K, paused 8ms, total 8ms
02-21 11:33:49.557: D/AndroidRuntime(1673): Shutting down VM
02-21 11:33:49.557: D/jdwp(1673): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
02-21 11:33:49.557: D/dalvikvm(1673): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
02-21 11:33:49.565: D/dalvikvm(1686): Late-enabling CheckJNI
02-21 11:33:49.569: I/ActivityManager(540): Start proc com.brainlogin.facedetectlib for activity com.brainlogin.facedetectlib/.FaceDetect: pid=1686 uid=10058 gids={50058, 1028, 1015}
02-21 11:33:49.569: D/MobileDataStateTracker(540): default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
02-21 11:33:49.589: D/(540): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8ba2ec8, tid 554
02-21 11:33:49.589: D/dalvikvm(1686): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
02-21 11:33:49.661: D/MobileDataStateTracker(540): default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
02-21 11:33:49.737: D/debug(1686): copy SUCCESS for flandmark_model.dat
02-21 11:33:49.745: D/CameraBridge(1686): Attr count: 3
02-21 11:33:49.777: D/dalvikvm(1686): GC_CONCURRENT freed 124K, 6% free 3502K/3692K, paused 3ms+1ms, total 17ms
02-21 11:33:49.789: D/dalvikvm(1686): GC_CONCURRENT freed 192K, 7% free 3819K/4088K, paused 0ms+1ms, total 5ms
02-21 11:33:49.789: D/dalvikvm(1686): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 3ms
02-21 11:33:49.801: D/dalvikvm(1686): GC_CONCURRENT freed 281K, 11% free 3935K/4404K, paused 2ms+0ms, total 4ms
02-21 11:33:49.801: D/dalvikvm(1686): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 3ms
02-21 11:33:49.809: D/dalvikvm(1686): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 255K, 11% free 3994K/4480K, paused 6ms, total 7ms
02-21 11:33:49.825: D/dalvikvm(1686): GC_CONCURRENT freed 283K, 8% free 4193K/4556K, paused 1ms+2ms, total 8ms
02-21 11:33:49.841: D/dalvikvm(1686): GC_CONCURRENT freed 229K, 7% free 4451K/4756K, paused 0ms+2ms, total 8ms
02-21 11:33:49.869: D/dalvikvm(1686): GC_CONCURRENT freed 257K, 7% free 4675K/5008K, paused 6ms+1ms, total 15ms
02-21 11:33:49.885: D/dalvikvm(1686): No JNI_OnLoad found in /system/lib/libc.so 0xa4fd7c78, skipping init
02-21 11:33:49.885: D/dalvikvm(1686): No JNI_OnLoad found in /system/lib/libm.so 0xa4fd7c78, skipping init
02-21 11:33:49.889: D/dalvikvm(1686): No JNI_OnLoad found in /system/lib/libz.so 0xa4fd7c78, skipping init
02-21 11:33:49.893: D/dalvikvm(1686): No JNI_OnLoad found in /system/lib/libdl.so 0xa4fd7c78, skipping init
02-21 11:33:49.893: D/dalvikvm(1686): No JNI_OnLoad found in /system/lib/liblog.so 0xa4fd7c78, skipping init
02-21 11:33:49.893: D/dalvikvm(1686): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.brainlogin.facedetectlib-1/libavutil.so 0xa4fd7c78
02-21 11:33:49.897: D/dalvikvm(1686): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.brainlogin.facedetectlib-1/libavutil.so 0xa4fd7c78
02-21 11:33:49.897: D/dalvikvm(1686): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.brainlogin.facedetectlib-1/libavutil.so 0xa4fd7c78, skipping init
02-21 11:33:49.897: D/dalvikvm(1686): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.brainlogin.facedetectlib-1/libjniavutil.so 0xa4fd7c78
02-21 11:33:49.901: E/dalvikvm(1686): dlopen("/data/app-lib/com.brainlogin.facedetectlib-1/libjniavutil.so") failed: dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/libhoudini.so" not found
02-21 11:33:49.901: W/dalvikvm(1686): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lorg/bytedeco/javacpp/avutil;
02-21 11:33:49.901: D/dalvikvm(1686): GC_CONCURRENT freed 453K, 11% free 4679K/5208K, paused 1ms+2ms, total 14ms
02-21 11:33:49.905: I/dalvikvm(1686): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class Lorg/bytedeco/javacpp/avutil; v=0x0
02-21 11:33:49.905: W/dalvikvm(1686): Exception Ljava/lang/NoClassDefFoundError; thrown while initializing Lorg/bytedeco/javacpp/avcodec$AVPacket;
02-21 11:33:49.905: D/AndroidRuntime(1686): Shutting down VM
02-21 11:33:49.905: W/dalvikvm(1686): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4cb5b20)
02-21 11:33:49.905: E/AndroidRuntime(1686): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use ARM binaries on an x86 device? If so, try to use binaries for x86 devices.

Comment: Thanks @SamuelAudet but I'm basically just grabbing all the javacv .so files that I find in the jar files from the official site and put them in the lib directory of the project, one subfolder for armeabi and another one for x86. So it should automatically use the x86 binaries (just like the physical device automatically used armeabi) if it doesn't have ARM translator. I don't know why the x86 .so files may not be detected automatically. By the way, I suspect the issue may come from Genymotion rather than javacv libs.